# In perl how do I get all matching result /g?

Tags: regex, perl

```
$string =~ /(pattern)/g;
```

I know I can get the matching result in `$1`,but how can I get **all** (`/g`) and push each result into an array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
$string = 'patternpattern';
@matches_array = $string =~ /(pattern)/g;
print "@matches_array";
```

That will produce the following output:

```
pattern pattern
```

Comment: Yes, but the parens turn out not to be strictly necessary in list context to get the capture.  There is an implicit set so `@a = /match/g` is the same as `@a = /(match)/g`.  Kinda weird.

Comment: @tchrist, Only if the pattern contains no captures. I guess what would screw up either usage, just in different ways.